# Splitting an N dimensional numpy array into multiple 1D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a simulation model that integrates a set of variables whose states are represented by numpy arrays of an arbitrary number of dimensions. After the simulation, I now have a list of arrays whose elements represent the variable state at a particular point in time.

In order to output the simulation results I want to split these arrays into multiple 1D arrays where the elements correspond to the same component of the state variable through time. Here is an example of a 2D state variable over a number of time steps.

```
import numpy as np

# Arbitrary state that is constant
arr = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))

# State variable through 3 time steps
state = [arr.copy() for _ in range(3)]

# Stack the arrays up to 3d. Axis could be rolled here if it makes it easier.
stacked = np.stack(state)
```

The output I need to get is:

```
[np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([1, 1, 1]), np.array([2, 2, 2]), ...]
```

I've tried doing `np.split(stacked, sum(stacked.shape[:-1]), axis=...)` (tried everything for `axis=`) but get the following error: `ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division`. Is there a way to do this using `np.split` or maybe `np.nditer` that will work for the general case?

I guess this would be equivalent to doing:

```
I, J, K = stacked.shape

result = []

for i in range(I):
    for j in range(J):
        result.append(stacked[i, j, :])
```

Which is also the ordering I'm hoping to get. Easy enough, however I'm hoping there is something in numpy that I can take advantage of for this that will be more general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I reshape it to a 9x3 array, then a simple `list()` will turn it into a list of 3 element arrays:

```
In [190]: stacked.reshape(-1,3)
Out[190]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8]])
In [191]: list(stacked.reshape(-1,3))
Out[191]: 
[array([0, 0, 0]),
 array([1, 1, 1]),
 array([2, 2, 2]),
 array([3, 3, 3]),
 array([4, 4, 4]),
 array([5, 5, 5]),
 array([6, 6, 6]),
 array([7, 7, 7]),
 array([8, 8, 8])]
```

`np.split(stacked.reshape(-1,3),9)` produces a list of 1x3 arrays.

`np.split` only works on one axis, but you want to split on the 1st 2 - hence the need for a reshape or ravel.

And forget about `nditer`.  That's a stepping stone to reworking code in cython.  It does not help with ordinary iteration - except that when used in `ndindex` it can streamline your `i,j` double loop:

```
In [196]: [stacked[idx] for idx in np.ndindex(stacked.shape[:2])]
Out[196]: 
[array([0, 0, 0]),
 array([1, 1, 1]),
 array([2, 2, 2]),
 array([3, 3, 3]),
 array([4, 4, 4]),
 array([5, 5, 5]),
 array([6, 6, 6]),
 array([7, 7, 7]),
 array([8, 8, 8])]
```

======================

With the different `state`, just stack on a different axis

```
In [302]: state
Out[302]: 
[array([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]]), array([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]]), array([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]])]
In [303]: np.stack(state,axis=2).reshape(-1,3)
Out[303]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8]])
```

`stack` is rather like `np.array`, except it gives more control over where the dimension is added.  But do look at it's code.

Comment: Lovely use of `list`! Looks pretty fast. Just to make it generic, maybe we could use the shape param there : `list(stacked.reshape(-1,stacked.shape[-1]))`.

Comment: I messed up on the example input array. Should be `stacked = np.stack(state)`. Updated the question so now your answer should be `list(stacked.reshape(3, -1).T)` I think? I agree with @Divakar, great use of `list`!

Comment: Looks great, I've just confirmed that this works for more than 2 dimensions. The general solution would be, `list(np.stack(state, axis=state[0].ndim).reshape(-1, len(state)))
`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) on a flattened version and cut into appropriate number of parts as `1D` lists, like so -

```
np.split(stacked.ravel(),np.prod(stacked.shape[:2]))
```

Sample run -

```
In [406]: stacked
Out[406]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5]],

       [[6, 6, 6],
        [7, 7, 7]]])

In [407]: np.split(stacked.ravel(),np.prod(stacked.shape[:2]))
Out[407]: 
[array([0, 0, 0]),
 array([1, 1, 1]),
 array([2, 2, 2]),
 array([3, 3, 3]),
 array([4, 4, 4]),
 array([5, 5, 5]),
 array([6, 6, 6]),
 array([7, 7, 7])]
```

Comment: Ah okay, I was wondering why I couldn't get `split` to work. I'll give this a shot later tonight

Comment: See edit - I think maybe `split` could still work but not sure.